# Ansible share default values between all host_vars files

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-inventory

I am configuring the network configuration of multiple hosts with the linux-system-roles.network role. This looks actually like this and works like a charm:

**host_vars/host-01.example.com.yml:**

```
network_connections:
  - name: ens18
    type: ethernet
    state: up
    ip:
      address:
        - 10.188.202.32/24
      gateway4: 10.188.202.1
      dns:
        - 10.188.202.20
        - 10.188.202.21
      dns_search:
        - example.com
```

Now, what i would like to achieve is, that i would like to define the environment specific dns configuration in one place and reference it in every host configuration. With anchors it would look something like that:

**host_vars/host-01.example.com.yml:**

```
dns_settings: &dns_settings
  dns:
    - 10.188.202.20
    - 10.188.202.21
  dns_search:
    - example.com


network_connections:
  - name: ens18
    type: ethernet
    state: up
    ip:
      address:
        - 10.188.202.32/24
      gateway4: 10.188.202.1
      <<: *dns_settings
```

But the problem is, that i have multiple host files - and as I have learned so far, it is not possible to use anchors between files. So what i would like to achieve is something like this:

**host_vars/all.yml:**

```
env_ip_settings:
  dns:
    - 10.188.202.20
    - 10.188.202.21
  dns_search:
    - example.com
```

**host_vars/host-01.example.com.yml:**

```
network_connections:
  - name: ens18
    type: ethernet
    state: up
    ip:
      address:
        - 10.188.202.32/24
      gateway4: 10.188.202.1
      << INSERT HERE env_ip_settings
```

**host_vars/host-02.example.com.yml:**

```
network_connections:
  - name: ens18
    type: ethernet
    state: up
    ip:
      address:
        - 10.188.202.33/24
      gateway4: 10.188.202.1
      << INSERT HERE env_ip_settings
```

What I tried so far is something like this:

**host_vars/all.yml:**

```
env_ip_settings:
  dns:
    - 10.188.202.20
    - 10.188.202.21
  dns_search:
    - example.com
```

**host_vars/host-01.example.com.yml:**

```
host_ip_settings:
  address:
    - 10.188.202.32/24
  gateway4: 10.188.202.1

network_connections:
  - name: ens18
    type: ethernet
    state: up
    ip: "{{ env_ip_settings + host_ip_settings }}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your use case does not get more complicated, simply refactor a bit the ip var for each host and combine it with the shared dns data:

Test file structure:

```
$ tree
.
├── inventories
│   └── default
│       ├── group_vars
│       │   └── all.yml
│       ├── hosts.yml
│       └── host_vars
│           ├── host-01.example.com.yml
│           └── host-02.example.com.yml
└── test_playbook.yml

4 directories, 5 files
```

`inventories/default/hosts.yml`

```yaml
---
my_group:
  hosts:
    host-01.example.com:
    host-02.example.com:
```

`inventories/default/group_vars/all.yml`

```yaml
---
dns_settings:
  dns:
    - 10.188.202.20
    - 10.188.202.21
  dns_search:
    - example.com
```

`inventories/default/host_vars/host-01.example.com`

```yaml
---
custom_ip_data:
  address:
    - 10.188.202.32/24
  gateway4: 10.188.202.1

network_connections:
  - name: ens18
    type: ethernet
    state: up
    ip: "{{ custom_ip_data | combine(dns_settings) }}"
```

`inventories/default/host_vars/host-01.example.com`

```yaml
---
custom_ip_data:
  address:
    - 10.188.202.33/24
  gateway4: 10.188.203.1

network_connections:
  - name: ens19
    type: ethernet
    state: up
    ip: "{{ custom_ip_data | combine(dns_settings) }}"
```

Using the above inventory, running the following `test_playbook.yml`

```yaml
---
- hosts: my_group
  gather_facts: false
  
  tasks:
    - name: Show computed network setting
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: network_connections
```

gives as a result:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/default/ test_playbook.yml 

PLAY [my_group] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show computed network setting] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host-01.example.com] => {
    "network_connections": [
        {
            "ip": {
                "address": [
                    "10.188.202.32/24"
                ],
                "dns": [
                    "10.188.202.20",
                    "10.188.202.21"
                ],
                "dns_search": [
                    "example.com"
                ],
                "gateway4": "10.188.202.1"
            },
            "name": "ens18",
            "state": "up",
            "type": "ethernet"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [host-02.example.com] => {
    "network_connections": [
        {
            "ip": {
                "address": [
                    "10.188.202.33/24"
                ],
                "dns": [
                    "10.188.202.20",
                    "10.188.202.21"
                ],
                "dns_search": [
                    "example.com"
                ],
                "gateway4": "10.188.203.1"
            },
            "name": "ens19",
            "state": "up",
            "type": "ethernet"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
host-01.example.com        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host-02.example.com        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. To pinpoint the problems with my approach: + is an invalid operator for dict's. combine does the job. An second: all.yml belongs to group_vars and not into host_vars.